# Why does my UITextfField seems to be NOT nil, even if I leave the field empty? My "else" part of the if-statment is not being read

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, uitextfield, conditional-statements

I am practicing swift programing by making an app that holds customers' data. The app has several text fields where people are supposed to type their name, email address, phone number, and quantity of products purchased. Then with a 'submit' button they save that information into the data base. However, if one of the fields is empty, an error should be thrown and a message should appear to the user letting him/her know that one of the fields empty.

The problem is that even if the textfield is empty, the compiler is not reading it as nil, so my condition is not working.

For simplicity, I am omitting a lot of code. I will only work with one UITextField (customer's name), and my condition will check if the TextField is empty or not. If empty, it should print "Please enter a valid name." if it is NOT nil, it should print the customer's name.

```
class RaffleViewControler: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var customerNameTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func addCustomerName(_ sender: UITextField) {


    }


    @IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!


    @IBAction func submitCustomer(_ sender: UIButton) {

           if let name = customerNameTextField.text {
            print(name)

        } else {
            print("Please enter a valid name")
        }
}
```

Alternatively, I was also checking my condition in the following format:

```
@IBAction func submitCustomer(_ sender: UIButton) {

               if customerNameTextField.text != nil {
                print("Congrats. Your data is in our database")

            } else {
                print("Please enter a valid name")
            }
  }
```

The problem:

Even if I leave the textfield empty, the compiler does not read the "else" part of the condition. Which seems to indicate that the field is never nil. What could be happening?

Comment: Sorry, but just to be sure, there's not a value already in it from the interface builder, right?

Comment: textfield has a property called hasText. `if customerNameTextField.hasText {`. another option is to test if it is not empty checking the text property `if customerNameTextField.text?.isEmpty == false { `

Comment: Btw this has already been asked so many times all over the web.

Comment: @LeoDabus You might be thinking of UITextView. I couldn't find hasText as a property of UITextField in the Apple docs.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Nope. I am talking about UITextField. Actually both of them.

Comment: textfield in when you not enter any value so that value is "" because that data type in string.

Comment: @MikeTaverne thats because it is an instance property of UIKeyInput https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614457-hastext but it is only available iOS10+

Comment: @LeoDabus you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text):

> This string is @"" by default.

I.e. it is not nil by default.

Answer (score 0):

To check empty UITextField your can use simply

```
txtFieldName.text?.isEmpty
```

this will give you **BOOL** value.

Comment: That will give you a `Bool?` value (in other words, an optional value).

Comment: Just to complement rmaddy's comment it can be `true`, `false` or `nil` (note that its default value is an empty string but you still need to threat it as an optional) so you need add `== true` or `== false`

Comment: @LeoDabus Another option besides adding `== true` (because of the optional), you can use `if txtFieldName.text!.isEmpty {` since `text` will never actually be `nil`. Even if you set it to `nil`, reading it immediately will return `""`.

Comment: @rmaddy thats true you can force unwrap it without any guilt but I prefer == true. Actually I use hasText property. I only use == true for optional Bool other than the text field text property

Comment: We are way off topic. The OP question is why is the text != nil condition not met.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check:

```
if self.customerNameTextField.text == "" {
// An empty text field.
} else {
// Not empty.
}
```